# If two cells has the same value in column 1, then move associated cells in row

Tags: excel, row

I wonder if there's a way to do the following:
I have a column A which contain numbers. If there are two or more number that's has the same value after eachother, then move values in B and C accordingly.

So column B and C is determined if the numbers in column A comes after eachother.

[image]

In the picture, Column A to C is my original data.
Column J to L is what I desire to achieve

Any ideas or feedback to get me in the right direction would be much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this in VBA, but I've done it using array formulas. I'm sure there will be a neater way in VBA.

The way I did it was, in K2 enter:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(F$1:F2,F2)=1,INDEX(B:B,SUM(1/COUNTIF(F$1:F2,F$1:F2))),G1)
```

And in L2:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(F$1:F2,F2)=1,INDEX(C:C,SUM(1/COUNTIF(F$1:F2,F$1:F2))),H1)
```

These are both array formulas, so you'll need to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter after you type them. Then they can just be copied down.

The way this works is:

```
IF(COUNTIF(F$1:F2,F2)=1,______,G1)
```

counts the number of times the value in F has appeared above it. If this is the first occurrence (=1), it needs to pick the value from column B, if not it just needs to equal the row above (G1).

```
INDEX(B:B,SUM(1/COUNTIF(F$1:F2,F$1:F2)))
```

works again by counting the number of times the value in F has occurred. Doing 1 over it, and summing them gives the number of unique values in column F up to that point. The index function then pulls the value in column B referring to that row.

Hope this makes sense and is what you're looking for!

Comment: Many thanks for your valuable help. Might I ask, if value 150 in cell A2 would appear again in cell A18, would it be difficult to modify the formula to reflect/take the occurrence again into consideration?

Anyway, many thanks for your time, much appreciated.

Comment: It depends what you'd want in K and L. Would it be 54 and 1 again? Or whatever would be in B11 and C11 ?

Comment: Whatever that would be in B11 and C11 :)